# Color opacity in OpenGL

Tags: java, opengl-es, colors

I would like to know how to print a partial color on an object in OpenGL. I mean, I want to be able to edit the level of the opacity of that color, and I don't know how to do it. The only thing I know is how to set the opacity of the entire texture:

```
gl.glColor4f(red, green, blue, **opacity**);
```

But with that function, I'm turning transparent the texture, and I would just like to edit the color level I'm giving to it.

Any tips? I'm using OpenGL-ES on Android.

Comment: Your question is not very clear, have you tried using glColor3f ?

Comment: While a cool idea, I dont actually thing (I am spitballing here) think that OpenGL ES nor a full opengl implementation provides for that type of operator / operation.

Comment: You would have to do this in a fragment shader: check if the colour is equal to the desired colour and then adjust the alpha.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way I can think to do this, but it requires some pre-rendering in the CPU prior to passing the texture to OpenGL would be to have 32 bit textures, then in a routine you build, when you bring in the parameter of the color that you want to set its Opacity, you simply run a loop that checks for that particular color, and sets its alpha component to whatever you desire.

```
// Algorithm Only
void setOpacityOfColor(char r, char g, char b, char opacToSet, RGBAType image[][]){

    for(int x = 0; x < image.width; x++){
        for(int y = 0; y < image.height; y++){
            if(image[x][y].r == r && image[x][y].g == g && image[x][y].b == b{
                image.alpha = opacToSet;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

I think this is correct if I truly understand your question.

Nice thing about this also is that it preserves the original color if you later wanted to set it back to opaque.  If you truly wanted to completely change the color you could do that as well, it would look more like the following:

```
// Algorithm Only
void setOpacityOfColor(char r, char g, char b, char newR, char newG, char newB, RGBAType image[][]){

    for(int x = 0; x < image.width; x++){
        for(int y = 0; y < image.height; y++){
            if(image[x][y].r == r && image[x][y].g == g && image[x][y].b == b{
                image.r = newR;
                image.g = newG;
                image.b = newB;
            }
        }
    }

}
```